# How to default the time for the date with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, getdate

Does anyone know how can I default the time for the date with SQL Server?

Example:

When I use `getdate()` and it will return me the current date and time. How can I get the current date but default the time portion to '10:00:00.000' ?

Comment: the database that im using is mssql

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=33116 lots of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for SQL Server ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/14493)):

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, 10, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Explanation: `GETDATE()` gives current date and time. Casting to `DATE` makes it date only (midnight time). Casting it again to `DATETIME` makes it compatible with `DATEADD`, which finally adds 10 hours to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below if you are using sql server.

```
select cast(cast(getdate()AS INT)+0.41667 as datetime)
```

Note time is scaled on a 0.0 to 0.9999, and the no. of hours are equally distributed. e.g. 0.5 will give 12a.m.

Answer (score 0):

This is from DB2. But same concept should work very DB. Just convert that date in to Timestamp

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE, TIME('10:00:00')) AS MY_DATE FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Answer (score 0):

in sql server 2008 and above:

```
select convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),convert(date,(GETDATE())))+' 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(datetime,convert(varchar,convert(date,getdate())) + ' 10:00:00.000')
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/14494)**

Answer (score 0):

Again, in Ms SQL Server, You can also use

`Select DateAdd(day, datediff(day, getdate()), 0) + 10/24.0`